# Julia set property: $J(f) = J(f^p)$

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

Given an holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, I got stuck trying to prove the equality of both Julia sets: $J(f) = J(f^p)$ for every $p\in\mathbb{N}$.

**$J(f^p)\subset J(f)$ is easy and I don't have troubles, but I don't know how to prove the reciprocal $J(f)\subset J(f^p)$.**

These are the definitions required:

A family of holomorphic maps $\mathcal{F}$ is said to be a normal family if any infinite sequence of elements of $\mathcal{F}$ contains a subsequence which converges uniformly on compact sets of their domain.

Julia set $J(f)$ is the complementary set of the Fatou set $F_f=\{z\text{ such that }\{f^n\}_n\text{ is normal in a neighbourhood of }z\}$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$J(f)\subset J(f^p)$ is equivalent to $F(f^p)\subset F(f)$.

Let $z_0 \in F(f^p)$ and $U$ a neighborhood of $z_0$ in which the family of iterates
$\{ f^{np} | n \in \Bbb N \}$ is normal. Then – since $f$ is uniformly continuous on
compact sets – each of the families 
$$
 A_q = \{ f^{np+q} | n \in \Bbb N \}  \quad (0 \le q \le p-1)
$$
is normal in $U$.

Now let $(f^{n_j})_j$ be a subsequence of the iterates of $f$. Then at least one
of the $A_q$ contains infinitely many of the $f^{n_j}$, i.e. there is a subsequence
$(f^{n_{j_k}})_k$  which is contained in some $A_q$, and therefore has a convergent
subsequence.

This shows that $\{ f^{n} | n \in \Bbb N \}$ is normal in a neighborhood of $z_0$.

Comment: Thank you Martin! I had done mostly the same but I forgot to use that every holomorphic function is uniformly continuous on compact sets. Thanks again :)